# Fetch after clone from mirror re-downloads everything

Tags: git

I have a local mirror of a remote repo, and a working copy cloned from this local mirror.
Now I do fetch on this working copy (against the remote) and expect it to get the recent changes added after the mirror creation.
But it appears to be downloading the entire history of everything again, judging by the amount of data being transferred:

```
git.exe fetch --progress -v "origin"
remote: Enumerating objects: 3443117, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (94/94), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (60/60), done.
Receiving objects:  57% (1966278/3443117), 30.85 GiB | 5.32 MiB/s
```

Can someone please explain what is going on? I guess I am not getting something about the mirror clones, or how the fetch figures out what data needs to be downloaded. I should be able to use whatever data I have locally and only get changes from the remote server, how?

The commands used are not too special:

```
git clone --mirror --reference c:\WORK\product git@github.com:company/product.git c:\TEST\mirror
cd mirror
git remote update

git clone --progress -v "c:\TEST\mirror" "C:\TEST\working"
```

I have then replaced origin url on a working copy before the fetch.

Update:

My mirror is missing any and all ref configurations. It makes it through receiving and resolving deltas, but then finishes with "error: Could not fetch origin" and no further details, and apparently the clone ends up being incomplete.

Comment: Please show how you have created your local mirror as well as how you cloned your working copy from it. Likely, there is some data missing in one of those repositories (e.g. because you used different remotes containing dfferent data, or you used a shallow clone in one of the repos).

Comment: I suspect some sort of incompleteness, not due to shallow or mismatching remotes though. I had some trouble creating the mirror, but it seem to have completed eventually. And it does contain a sizable objects pack, that I'd expect to be at least somewat useful.

Comment: I wonder if `--reference` and `--mirror` are interacting badly, though I can't imagine why they would.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out my mirror was in fact incomplete. I wasn't sure at first if what I am seeing is not correct for a bare repo, and git output didn't make it clear either.

Somehow initial clone did not configure any refs, nor did consequent updates and fetches.

A clean `clone` without `--reference` solved the problem for me. Now refs are visible on the mirror, and working copies checked out from it only download newer changes as they should.